# Functions - callback vs fallback

Tags: functions

While seeing the source code of some themes or plugins, I have noticed that, sometimes these two words are used to denote/indicate other functions.

What's the difference between them? Which function should be called `callback` function and which is `fallback`?

Can you give me an example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not really a question in the focus of WordPress, is also in other programming languages and in our speaking language a topic. Maybe I can clear the difference between these words with a non coding example.

### Callback

A return of a situation to a state. Like a call with the telephone to a message of the phone or the answering machine to a defect of a product.

In the coding context is a callback a function/method which executed after the current effect is finished.

### Fallback

An act of falling back. Like an alternative plan to the current idea, progress.

In context of the computer is a fallback typically a backup of the current data to fallback to a time stamp.